# Cast safely a sessionScope value in Java

Tags: java

I have a Map object stored in a sessionScope. If I cast it to the following object:

```
Map<String,Object> mapItem = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
```

I get a Type safety warning. Type safety:

Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,Object>

I tried to cast the scope variable to an object and check what instance the object is but then I can not directly check if it is of Map<String,Object>. So I wonder how I should handle this further?

```
Object obj = entry.getValue();
if(obj instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
    //not sure what to do here
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: If `entry.getValue()` returns `Map` or even `Object`, there is no way to tell the compiler that the cast is safe. If you know it is safe, then just use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the variable `mapItem` to suppress the warning.

Comment: Java generic types are a runtime thing not a compile time thing so there is nothing you can do to check this information on compile time. Suppressing the warning is the only option. Look up Java generics type erasure for more information.

Comment: @Tarmo this ist wrong. It's the other way round.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I got it messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the generics applied to the original `Map` your `Entry` is from. Consider these examples

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, Object> mapItem = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue(); // Will have unchecked warning
}

// Declare another map specifying the values type more specifically
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, Object> mapItem = entry.getValue(); // Will not require cast
}
```

The issue occurs because the compiler doesn't know anything more about the values type than its an `Object`. You know its a `Map<String, Object>` so you can tell the compiler that with generics and it will enforce that in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to achieve that;
Look at how to handle it in Gson:

```
 Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
 new Gson().fromJson("{}", mapType);
```